# Minimum and maximum length of X509 serialNumber

Tags: x509

The CA/Browser Forum Baseline Requirements section 7.1 states the following:

> CAs   SHOULD  generate    non‐sequential  Certificate serial  numbers that    exhibit at  least   20  bits    of  entropy.

At the mean time, RFC 5280 section 4.1.2.2 specifies:

> Certificate users MUST be able to handle serialNumber values up to 20 octets.  Conforming CAs MUST NOT use serialNumber values longer than 20 octets.

Which integer range can I use in order to fullfill both requirements. It is my understanding that the max. value will be 2^159 (730750818665451459101842416358141509827966271488). What is the min. value?

Answer (score 2):

The CAB requirement has changed to minimum of 64 bit entropy. Since the leading bit in the representation for positive integers must be 0 there are a number of strategies:

- produce random bit string with 64 bits. If leading bit is 1 then prepend 7 more random bits. This has the disadvantage that it is not obvious if the generation considered 63 or 64 bits
- produce random bit string with 64 bits and add leading 0 byte. This is still compact (wastes only 7-8 bit) but is obvious that it has 64 bit entropy
- produce a random string longer than 64 bit, for example 71 or 127 bit (+leading 0 bit). 16 byte seems to be a common length and well under the 20 byte limit.

BTW since it is unclear if the 20 byte maximum length includes a potential 0 prefix for interop reasons you should not generate more than 159 bit

A random integer with x bit entropy can be produced with generating a random number between 0 and (2^x)-1 (inclusive)

Comment: Why not just use unsigned integers ffs? All these non-sensical workarounds, just because the upper bit is used for sign and they don't want negative numbers *facepalm*.

Comment: X.509 is from 1988, and you cannot easily change existing standards, and when adding a new version you might need to have the changes in it small for good adoption. Thats why I suspect they need to stick with the `CertificateSerialNumber  ::=  INTEGER` definition from RFC2459.

Comment: Regarding the minimum length of an X.509 serial number - I recently received a certificate with a serial number of 0x91AB and was mildly worried about that. Should I be?

Comment: @user9645 they used to be even shorter, like 1. i think recent CAS compatible with CAB requirements don't do that, but if it is homegrown (company PKI or self signed) it can still happen. Unless this is a high security app, I would not worry (However future software might reject it)

Comment: @eckes - Not sure how it was generated, but it's a SHA256(RSA) certificate with not-before = Apr 2020, and with OU=DoD, so...

Comment: @user9645 it depends on the issuer, mostly